# Why does reinterpret_cast only work for 0?

Tags: c++, types, casting, floating-point

While studying the behavior of casts in C++, I discovered that `reinterpret_cast`-ing from `float*` to `int*` only works for `0`:

```cpp
float x = 0.0f;

printf("%i\n", *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&x));
```

prints `0`, whereas

```cpp
float x = 1.0f;

printf("%i\n", *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&x));
```

prints `1065353216`.

Why? I expected the latter to print `1` just like `static_cast` would.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast - what did  you expect?

Comment: @Mat edited it.

Comment: The bit patterns in memory are the same for integer `0` and floating point `0.0`.  That's not true for any other constant that I'm aware of.

Comment: The binary representations of `int 0` and `float 0.0f` are the same (all bits set to zero), but the binary representations of `int 1` and `float 1.0f` are not the same.  See [IEEE Standard 754 Floating Point Numbers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ieee-standard-754-floating-point-numbers/)

Comment: Why would you expect `1`? `reinterpret_cast` is a very blunt tool, and apart from getting you into undefined behavior territory at the slightest miss-step, it doesn't actually do anything but treat the raw data as some other type.

Comment: Both `reinterpret_cast` and `dynamic_cast` are better avoided. Most of the time, the only cast you should be using is the `static_cast`.

Comment: @Ron except, of course, in cases where `static_cast` can't be used, and `reinterpret_cast`/`dynamic_cast` do make sense to use.

Comment: Float is represented as a 32-bit IEEE 754 floating-point number, while integer isn't.
C11, 6.2.6.2p5: "For any integer type, the object representation where all the bits are zero shall be a representation of the value zero in that type." 
That's why they are the same as zeroes.
edit: float is 32-bit, as stated below, fixed that

Comment: @JakubNovák So as to be entirely clear and to not confuse the questioner, you are not claiming that the result *must* be zero, right? Because the program exhibits undefined behavior. In fact, what are you saying exactly because I'm confused.

Comment: @Ron I downvoted the question. The OP says "I expected the latter to print `1`" but doesn't explain the rationale for that expectation. The OP's issue is that he has a broken expectation. But how can we fix that if we don't know why he has that expectation? If the question is edited to explain the expectation, I'll change to an upvote.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Fair enough. Appreciate the response.

Comment: @Ron: I downvoted because the questioner appears to be using `reinterpret_cast` without _researching_ what it does or when they should be using it.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you see a `reinterpret_cast` or a c-style cast, inspect the code with high vigilance. It's not always wrong, but the likelihood is high enough to be extra careful. If you think you need a `reinterpret_cast` or c-style cast, explore other options. If you're casting to remove an error or warning, you're probably just moving the error from compile time to run time.

Comment: Edited with an explanation for the expectation.

Comment: Super, I don't think that'll satisfy the people asking for explanation. That's basically saying, "I expect `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` to behave the same."  And that will lead to "Can you explain why you expected that behaviour?" I think the point they're trying to get across is, "What misreading of documentation (or correct reading of incorrect documentation) lead you to this conclusion?"

Comment: *"just like static_cast would"* - Umm `static_cast<int*>(&x)` would be a hard error. So those aren't comparable. If, however, you are talking about `static_cast<int>(x)`, then that's hardly the same either. That one is asking for a value conversion of the objects, not of their addresses.

Comment: So basically you downvoted because I didn't already know the answer to the question?

Comment: Sometimes that happens. One of the valid downvote reasons is insufficient research, and the differences between the various casts as well as when to use them are well documented and should be sufficient to make the question unnecessary. Unfortunately the documentation isn't always that easy to understand, but if you have read it, then the question changes from "Why doesn't this work?" to "I read <documentation> and it said <information>, but when I tried it <code goes here> the results were <results>. What gives?" demonstrating research, effort, and the other things that make a good question.

Comment: Ah now i see thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `reinterpret_cast` says to reinterpret the bits of its operand. In your example, the operand, `&x`, is the address of a `float`, so it is a `float *`. `reinterpret_cast<int *>` asks to reinterpret these bits as an `int *`, so you get an `int *`. If pointers to `int` and pointers to `float` have the same representation in your C++ implementation, this may<sup>1</sup> work to give you an `int *` that points to the memory of the `float`.

However, the `reinterpret_cast` does not change the bits that are pointed to. They still have their same values. In the case of a `float` with value zero, the bits used to represent it are all zeros. When you access these through a dereferenced `int *`, they are read and interpreted as an `int`. Bits that are all zero represent an `int` value of zero.

In the case of a `float` with value one, the bits used to represent it in your C++ implementation are, using hexadecimal to show them, 3f800000<sub>16</sub>. This is because the exponent field of the format is stored with an offset, so there are some non-zero bits to show the value of the exponent. (That is part of how the floating-point format is encoded. Conceptually, `1.0f` is represented as + 1.00000000000000000000000<sub>2</sub> • 2<sup>0</sup>. Then the + sign and the bits after the “1.” are stored literally as zero bits. However, the exponent is stored by adding 127 and storing the result as an eight-bit integer. So an exponent of 0 is stored as 127. The represented value of the exponent is zero, but the bits that represent it are not zero.) When you access these bits through a dereferenced `int *`, they are read and interpreted as an `int`. These bits represent an `int` value of 1065353216 (which equals 3f800000<sub>16</sub>).

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The C++ standard does not guarantee this, and what actually happens is dependent on other factors.

Answer (score 6):

In both cases the behaviour of the program is undefined, because you access an object through a glvalue that doesn't refer to an object of same or compatible type.

What you have observed is one possible behaviour. The behaviour could have been different, but there is no guarantee of that it would have been, and it wasn't. Whether you expected one result or another is not guaranteed to have effect on the behaviour.

> I expected the latter to print 1 just like static_cast would.

It is unreasonable to expect reinterpret_cast to behave as static_cast would. They are wildly different and one can not be substituted for the other. Using static_cast to convert the pointers would make the program ill-formed.

rainterpret_cast should not be used unless one knows what it does, and knows that its use is correct. The practical use cases are rare.

Here are a few examples that have well defined behaviour, and are guaranteed to print 1:

```
int i = x;
printf("%i\n", i);

printf("%i\n", static_cast<int>(x));

printf("%g\n", x);

printf("%.0f\n", x);
```

---

Given that we've concluded that behaviour is undefined, there is no need for further analysis.

But we *can* consider why the behaviour may have happened to be what we observed. It is however important to understand that these considerations will not be useful in controlling what the result will be while the behaviour is undefined.

The binary representations of 32 bit IEEE 754 floating point number for 1.0f and +0.0f happen to be:

```
0b00111111100000000000000000000000
0b00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Which also happen to be the binary representation of the integer 1065353216 and 0. Is it a coincidence that the output of the programs were these specific integers whose binary representation match the representation of the float value? Could be in theory, but it probably isn't.

Comment: Totally true, but does not explain the observed results.

Comment: @MarkRansom Undefined behaviour is explanation for all behaviour of programs that have undefined behaviour.

Comment: It is a sufficient explanation but not a very satisfying one.

Comment: But you can't use undefined behaviour to explain another behaviour, since it is undefined.

Comment: @MarkRansom When someone doesn't understand that their program exhibits undefined behavior, pointing out that it does is extremely helpful and valuable. Figuring out what "happens to happen" on their particular combination of compiler, library, compiler options, and so on is often counterproductive because it will distract from the key message that the behavior is unpredictable. It's actively harmful to people to give complex answers to simple questions when there's a very simple point the questioner *must* absorb.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the fact that they see a result that makes sense to them under certain circumstances gets in the way of absorbing that crucial point.  Especially if it's consistently reproducible, which in this case it would be.

Comment: @MarkRansom If you look at Jakub Novák's comment on the question about "why it's zero", you can see how such comments are more harmful than helpful. Is he saying it has to be zero? Or that's why it just happens to be zero? (Which is incorrect.) (Is it consistently reproducible? You don't even know the OP's platform. How do you know it's reproducible on their platform?)

Comment: @eerorika: Undefined behavior is not an explanation of behavior. It explains why the behavior is **permitted** by the language standard, but it does not explain why a particular behavior **occurred**. Nobody defined what makes the sun rise, but we nonetheless figured out good models that explain it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sure. But when someone doesn't understand that their program exhibits undefined behavior, the most important thing is to get them to understand that it does. Figuring out why some particular thing "happens to happen" on their combination of compiler, libraries, CPU, and so on is much less important than making absolutely sure they 100% absorb the fact that the result is unpredictable from the language rules.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `Undefined behavior is not an explanation of behavior. ` That's pointless hair-splitting in my opinion. It is an explanation for why the behaviour is allowed. Of course, that behaviour happens because of what the compiler produced, and the CPU executed, but that is too banal to have to explain. Why wouldn't the compiler produce something that it is allowed to produce? Why shouldn't the output be something that it is allowed to be? Making any conclusion based on those is pointless because those conclusion would be based on something that is not guaranteed to be reproduced.

Comment: Re “Why wouldn't the compiler produce something that it is allowed to produce?”: When there is undefined behavior, the compiler is allowed to produce a program that erases all your files. But it does not, absent some latent presence of actions to that end in the program. It would be wasteful and harmful, and it would require effort by the compiler developers to make that happen. They do not do that. What happens when there is behavior not defined by the standard is not some random or maliciously designed thing. What happens is a consequence of how compilers are designed, among other things…

Comment: So, that is why the compiler would not produce “something” it is allowed to produce. When something goes awry, the results are not generally random. They contain clues to what goes awry, and we can use those clues to diagnose and locate the problem. There is value in them. There is value in knowing how things go wrong when they go wrong. There is also value in knowing how wrong things can go. If the simplest error could kill people, then we must take exceptional care. If the simplest error could delete all your files, then we would take great care. But, if we know that simply having some…

Comment: … “undefined” behavior is not likely to cause a great catastrophe and is merely going to screw up one program execution, then it would be wasteful to take great care with the program. We can go ahead, make some mistake, try out the program, fix it, and learn. So, no, “undefined behavior” is not a black box or a bogeyman. It is something we can look into, learn from, and benefit from.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `the compiler is allowed to produce a program that erases all your files` Maybe it did? I wonder if OP checked whether their files are still there. There are worse things that can [and have happened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therac-25) due to UB though. I had seen it unnecessary to explain that output of  `1065353216` is not considered a seriously bad outcome, and thus not something that the compiler / OS / CPU would have needed to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

`float` has a different representation than `int`, so that you cannot treat `float` representation as `int`. That's undefined behaviour in C++.

It so happens that on modern architectures a 0-bit pattern represents any fundamental type with value of 0 (so that one can `memset` with zeroes a `float` or `double`, or integer types, or pointer types and get 0-valued object, that's what that `calloc` function does). This is why that cast-and-dereference "works" for 0 value, but that is still undefined behaviour. The C++ standard doesn't require a 0-bit pattern to represent a 0 floating point value, neither it requires any specific representation of floating point numbers.

A conversion of `float` to `int` is implicit and no cast is required.

A solution:

```
float x = 1.0f;
int x2 = x;
printf("%i\n", x2);
// or
printf("%i\n", static_cast<int>(x));
```